# Django model variables - Unique

Tags: django, models

I am terribly sorry for the crummy title to this question. I can't think of how to phrase it in a simple context.

---

I am making a simple photo gallery. The admin can create a gallery page and upload images to it. For each gallery I want there to be a single banner image from one of the photos.  The Photo model has a CharField which will tell if its a banner or not. Is there a way to make the variable to allow only one 'B' for every photo that belongs to a Gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a `unique_together` variable for your class. If names of your fields are `album` and `banner`, you should add this line to Meta class of your model.

```
unique_together = (("album", "banner"),)
```

[Django Documents, unique-together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)

And i think, using charfield for a boolean value isn't a correct choice. You should change your `banner` field as BooleanField.

Comment: Thanks. This might be exactly what I need.  On a side note, the charfield will support more options but it wasn't necessary for my problem. I just need to make sure there is only one banner per project.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) field?

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
...
banner = models.OneToOneField(Photo)
```

this way, you have an unique relationship between a gallery and a photo.